# How to hide KITE box in spyder 4

Tags: python, spyder, kite

I am getting this box open again and again in spyder 4 and this is really frustrating me. How can I disable this KITE box in spyder 4.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Tools, Preferences, Completion and Linting

Is *Enable Kite* toggled on or off?